# JSDoc doesn't print a param of a custom type (typedef)

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I've defined a custom type via `@typedef`:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} FILE_DATA
 * @property {NodeJS.ReadableStream} fileStream
 * @property {string} fileUUID
 */
```

Then I apply this custom type in a method signature:

```js
/**
 * Upload file to Dropbox
 *
 * @param {FILE_DATA} fileData - file data to be stored
 * @returns {Promise<Readonly<{fileName: string, folderUUID: string, isSucceeded: boolean, message: string}>>} file upload result
 */
export const fileUpload = async function fileUpload(fileData) {…}
```

When I generate a JSDoc, I expect that `fileUpload()` documentation will contain a custom type, in fact the only documentation about `fileUpload()` is:

> (static, constant) fileUpload
> Upload file to Dropbox

How to make JSDoc showing more details about `fileUpload()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue it's important to add an annotation `@function`/`@method` to the function `fleUpload`:

```js
/**
 * Upload file to Dropbox
 *
 * @function
 * @param {FILE_DATA} fileData - file data to be stored
 * @returns {Promise<Readonly<{fileName: string, folderUUID: string, isSucceeded: boolean, message: string}>>} file upload result
 */
export const fileUpload = async function fileUpload(fileData) {
```

Once I've added this annotation, JSDoc puts `fileUpload` under the methods and not members.

Comment: Doesn't refactoring your code to `export async function fileUpload(fileData) { ... }` negate the need for `@method` ? The initial variable assignment seems unnecessary.

Comment: I've decided to use strict named function expressions over function declarations to gain more control over a code, e.g. no hoisting, therefore the code refactoring to `export async function fileUpload(fileData) { ... }` isn't so relevant for my use case.

Comment: OK, that's fair enough. In which case I can only assume `fileUpload` is used elsewhere in the same file (even though it's being `export`'ed), or maybe the functions body references outer variables/functions - otherwise the decision to use _"strict named function expressions over function declarations"_ due to hoisting is moot.

Comment: @RobC, I use `export` to expose `fileUpload` outside the module, to be able to call the function from another module. For me, the key issue of migration to JS was its unpredictable (comparing to C/Java/C#) behavior that's why I decided to stick as much as possible to the most strict approach.